# Login button with error password goes to next view

Tags: ios, objective-c, navigation

I created login page with username and password.when i click login button, wrong password message will appear.But it goes to next page.can anyone help me? my code is below:

```
-(IBAction)enterCredentials
{
    if ([[credtialsDictionary objectForKey:usernameField.text]isEqualToString:passwordField.text])
    {
        UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"correct password" message:@"This password is correct." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil,nil];
        [alert show];
    }
    else
    {
        UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Incorrect password" message:@"This password is incorrect." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil,nil];
        [alert show];
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please put some code here so we can see what is wrong in your code.

Comment: show the code which allows you to navigate on to the next page. The above code only contains alerts.

Comment: Whatever you have posted looks like it will work. May be you could post more code, so we can help you.

Comment: i tried with dismissModalViewController.but it shows as depricted

Comment: i created next page using storyboard

Comment: @MadhuM: Just set your delegate nil in this line UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Incorrect password" message:@"This password is incorrect." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil,nil]; if you want to show alert only on wrong password.

Comment: Is it going to the next page when you press the ok button from alertview?

Answer (score 2):

You need to implement

```
- (void)performSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier sender:(id)sender
```

method to cancel or allow segue to happen.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have create segue link for `UIButton` tap event to next `UIViewController` in Storyboard, So what ever you do it will push to next controller.

Go to Storybord

1. Remove that segue from Storyboard and do push navigation from code.

[image]

2. Select next `UIViewController` and give **unique storyboard id**  like below reference image.

[image]

3. Go to controller class from where `-(IBAction)` method is calling.
4. In that method create an instance of next view controller.

Update code with following:

```
-(IBAction)enterCredentials
{
    if ([[credtialsDictionary objectForKey:usernameField.text]isEqualToString:passwordField.text])
    {
        UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"correct password" message:@"This password is correct." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil,nil];
        [alert show];

        UIViewController *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@“ViewController”];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
    }
    else
    {
        UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Incorrect password" message:@"This password is incorrect." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil,nil];
        [alert show];
    }
}
```